# Operator Overloading: How to add and compare data of two class "Integer" and "Fraction"

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism, operator-overloading

I have two classes **Integer** and **Fraction** and one abstract class **Number**. I am suppose to perform addtion operation by overloading `+` and also I need to check equality of values using overloading of `==` operator on these classes.

Operations to be performed

**1. Add Integer + Integer = Integer**

**2. Add Fraction + Fraction = Fraction**

**3. Add Integer + Fraction = Fraction**

I have been able to do 1st and 2nd operation but not able to do addition of integer and fraction.

Below is the code snippet:

1. Number.h

   ```
    #pragma once
   #include <iostream>
   template<class T>

   class Number
   {
       virtual const T operator+ (const T &) = 0;
       virtual void display(std::ostream &) const = 0;
       virtual bool operator==(const T& rhs) const = 0;

   };
   ```
2. Integer.h

   ```
    #pragma once
    #include "Number.h"
    #include "Fraction.h"
   class Integer : public Number<Integer>
   {
       int intValue;

   public:
       void display(std::ostream &) const;
       int getValue() const;
       void setValue(int);
       Integer() {}
       Integer(int num);
       const Integer operator+ (const Integer &);
       virtual ~Integer() {}
       bool operator==(const Integer&) const;

   };
   ```
3. Integer.cpp

   ```
   #include "Integer.h"
   #include "Number.h"
   #include <iostream>
   #include <string>

   // parameterized constructor
   Integer::Integer(int num)
   {
       intValue = num;
   }

   // return integer value

   int Integer::getValue() const
   {
       return this->intValue;
   }

   void Integer::setValue(int x)
   {
       this->intValue = x;
   }

   // operator "+" overloading
   const Integer Integer::operator+(const Integer &secondNumber)
   {
       Integer  temp = this->intValue + secondNumber.intValue;
       return temp;
   }

   // operator "=" overloading 
   void Integer::display(std::ostream& stream) const
   {
       stream << this->intValue;
   }

   // comparasion operator overload
   bool Integer::operator==(const Integer& rhs) const
   {
       return this->intValue == rhs.intValue;
   }
   ```
4. Fraction.h

   ```
    #pragma once
    #include "Number.h"
    #include "Integer.h"

    class Fraction : public Number<Fraction>
    {
        Integer _numerator;
        Integer _denominator;
        public:
       void display(std::ostream &) const;
       Fraction() = delete;
       Fraction(const int &, const int &);
       const Fraction operator+ (const Fraction &);
       int gcdCalculate(int  val1, int  val2);
       int lcmCalculate(const int  val1, const int  val2);
       virtual ~Fraction() {}
       bool operator==(const Fraction& rhs) const;
    };
   ```
5. Fraction.cpp

   ```
   #include "Fraction.h"
   #include <iostream>

   // parameterised constructor 
   Fraction::Fraction(const int & num, const int & den)
   {
       _numerator.setValue(num);
       _denominator.setValue(den);
   }

   // display the fraction value
   void Fraction::display(std::ostream & stream) const
   {
           if (this->_denominator == 0)
            std::cout << "Undefined: " << this->_numerator.getValue() << "/" << this->_denominator.getValue() << " (Divide By Zero Exception)";
   else
           stream << this->_numerator.getValue() << "/" << this->_denominator.getValue();
   }

   // "+" operator overloading
   const Fraction Fraction::operator+(const Fraction &numberTwo)
   {
       int lcm = lcmCalculate(this->_denominator.getValue(), numberTwo._denominator.getValue());
       int multiplier1 = 0;
       if (this->_denominator.getValue())
       multiplier1 = lcm / this->_denominator.getValue();
       int multiplier2 = 0;
       if (numberTwo._denominator.getValue())
           multiplier2 = lcm / numberTwo._denominator.getValue();
       return Fraction((this->_numerator.getValue() * multiplier1) + (numberTwo._numerator.getValue() * multiplier2), lcm);
   }


    // LCM Calculation

   int Fraction::lcmCalculate(const int  val1, const int  val2)
   {
       int temp = gcdCalculate(val1, val2);
       return temp ? (val1 / temp * val2) : 0;
   }

   // GCD Calculation
   int Fraction::gcdCalculate(int val1, int  val2)
   {
       for (;;)
       {    
           if (val1 == 0) return val2;
               val2 %= val1;
           if (val2 == 0) return val1;
               val1 %= val2;
       }
   } 

   // comparision operator overload 
   bool Fraction::operator==(const Fraction& rhs) const
   {
       Integer numCheck = this->_numerator;
       Integer denCheck = this->_denominator;
       if (rhs._numerator.getValue())
           numCheck.setValue(numCheck.getValue() / rhs._numerator.getValue());
       if (rhs._numerator.getValue())
           denCheck.setValue(denCheck.getValue() / rhs._denominator.getValue());
       if (numCheck == denCheck) {
           return true;
       }
       return false;
   }
   ```

QUESTION:

1. I am confused as how to add Integer + Fraction class.
2. Do I need to create another class which will inherit from Number class.
3. How to overload `oprator+` present in `Number Class`.

Suppose I try to add `Integer + Fraction = Fraction` in the Integer class itself then I will have something like 
Example

```
class Integer : public Number<Integer>
{
    const Fraction operator+(const Fraction &);
}
    const Fraction Integer::operator+(const Fraction &numberTwo)
{
                                              ^^ I will get error here           
    // Addition opeartion
}
```

Please help me.

Comment: There is no `Number` class - `Number` is a class template. `Fraction` and `Integer` have no common base class. You have two abstract classes, `Number<Integer>` and `Number<Fraction>`, and these two are unrelated.

Comment: Why negative votes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question, the solution is to not use member function overloads, but to create a non-member function overload, e.g.

```
Fraction operator+(Integer const& integer, Fraction const& fraction)
{
    // Logic to add the integer and fraction here
    // Perhaps something like...
    Fraction f(integer.getValue(), 1);  // Create fraction
    return f + fraction;
}
```

The code above uses the `Fraction::operator+` function to add the integer.

Comment: Where shall I place this code you have mentioned. And do I need to keep it friend or something. I am new to this stuff. Kindly guide  me. Thanks.

Comment: If you provide access to Fraction's numerator and denominator (as you do for the Integer's value), the operators won't need to be friends: they can just use the public interface. You can put them in a .h + .cpp file of their own, or inline in a header file. There's no need to make Integer and Fraction depend on (or even know about) each other.

Comment: @joachim: Kindly help me a little.

Comment: @Unbreakable Updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

While you can add an `Integer`+`Fraction` operator to your current design like Joachim suggested, that's going to result in some code duplication or at least some unnecessary boilerplate.

I suggest an alternative design instead: Make `Integer` [convertible](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast) to `Fraction`. After all, any integer can be represented by the `Fraction` type, right?

You can make `Integer` convertible in two ways: By adding a [conversion function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator) to `Integer`, or by adding a [converting constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/converting_constructor) to `Fraction`.

I recommend choosing the converting constructor approach, because `Fraction` already depends on `Integer` type and so the cast operator would result in a circular dependency, just like your member operator attempt. I'll leave the implementation as an exercise.

This design requires that the addition operator is implemented as a non-member overload:

```
Fraction operator+(Fraction const& left, Fraction const& right)
```

With the converting constructor, this function can handle any combination of (F + F), (F + I) and (I + F).