# Operator overloading for add and compare data of Integer and Fraction classes

Tags: c++, oop, templates, c++11, polymorphism

Similar to this problem posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36328735/operator-overloading-how-to-add-and-compare-data-of-two-class-integer-and-fr). I Need to create three classes:

1. "Number" class supports three operations,such as, “display”, “==”,
   and “+”;
2. "Integer class" that represented by integer;
3. "Fraction" class is represented by numerator and denominator.

Requirements:

1. It should support the operations: (a) Integer (I) + Fraction (F),
   (b) F+I, (c) F+F, (d) I+I, and comparing them
2. The caller of the + operation doesn't need to know the return type.

I could solve the problem till requirement# 1. However, couldn't figure out the second requirement yet. Any help would be appreciated.
To keep it brief, I am going to share the header file of my code below, function definition of the code can be shared if needed.

1. Number.h

```html
#pragma once

template<class T>
class Number
{
public:
    bool operator== (const T&)
    {
        return impl().operator == ();
    }

    T operator+ (const T &) const
    {
        return impl().operator+();
    }


    template <typename Stream>
    void display(Stream& os) const
    {
        impl().display(os);
    }

private:
    T& impl() {
        return *static_cast<T*>(this);
    }
    T const & impl() const {
        return *static_cast<T const *>(this);
    }

};
```

2. Integer.h

```html
#pragma once
#include "Number.h"

class Integer : public Number<Integer>
{
    int intValue{0};
public:
    template <typename Stream>
    void display(Stream& os) const
    {
        os << this->intValue << '\n';
    }

    Integer() = default;
    ~Integer() = default;

    Integer(int num);
    int getIntValue() const;
    bool operator== (const Integer &);
    Integer operator+ (const Integer &) const;
};
```

3. Fraction.h

```html
#pragma once
#include <math.h>
#include "Number.h"
#include "Integer.h"
#include <iostream>

class Fraction : public Number<Fraction>
{
    int _numerator{0};
    int _denominator{1};
    int gcdCalculate(int val1, int val2) const;
    int lcmCalculate(const int val1, const int val2) const;

public:
    template <typename Stream>
    void display(Stream& os) const

    {int tempNum = this->_numerator;
    int tempDen = this->_denominator;
    double tempFrac = (double)tempNum/(double)tempDen;
    double intpart;

        if (this->_denominator==0)
        {

        std::cout << "Undefined " << this->_numerator << "/" << this->_denominator << "(Divide by zero exception)";
        }
    else if (this->_denominator==1){
        std::cout << this->_numerator << std::endl;
        }

    else {
        os << this->_numerator << "/";
        os << this->_denominator << '\n';}
    }

    Fraction() = default;
    Fraction(int num, int den);

    ~Fraction() = default;

    bool operator== (const Fraction &);
    bool operator== (const Integer &);
    friend bool operator== (const Integer&, const Fraction&);

    Fraction operator+ (const Fraction &) const;
    Fraction operator+ (const Integer &) const;
    friend Fraction operator+ (const Integer&, const Fraction&);
};
```

main.cpp

```html
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


template <typename INumberType>
void GenericDisplay(const Number<INumberType>& num) //Here we are calling through the Number<> Interface
{
    num.display(cout);
}

int main()
{
    Fraction fracOne(1,4);
    Fraction fracTwo(2,8);
    Integer intOne(30);
    Integer intTwo(30);
    Fraction sumOfFractionOneTwo = fracOne + fracTwo;
    Integer sumOfIntegerOneTwo = intOne + intTwo;
    Fraction sumOfFractionOneAndIntegerOne = integerOne + fracOne;
    Fraction sumOfFractionTwoAndIntegerTwo = fracTwo + intTwo;
    return 0;
}
```

In this code, caller of the + operator knows the return type, e.g., in the int main() caller defined returned type "**Fraction** sumOfFractionOneAndIntegerOne = integerOne + fracOne;". Which is incorrect!

The way I want, caller should not know the return type. e.g., "**Number** sumOfFractionOneAndIntegerOne = integerOne + fracOne;"

Again, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Since this is tagged as C++11, would you be interested in std::ratio? I'm not posting this as an answer because it circumvents the problem instead of solving it.

Answer (score 1):

Since the type is statically known, the caller can use auto for the type of the variable, so that the type is deduced instead of explicitly specified. Otherwise, you may be looking for virtual inheritance, which allows an abstract base to be used as the type while derived classes provide implementation for further operators.

Comment: Hi John, thanks for your answer. I progressed a bit following your answer. I made the following function in the number class:
   `template<typename T1, typename T2>`
    `auto addition(T1 left, T2 right) -> decltype(left+right)`
   `{
        return left+right;
    }`
Now it can deduce the type. However, I couldn't implement it for overloading '+' function. e.g., I wanted to use `auto operator+(T1 left, T2 right) -> decltype(left+right)` instead of `auto addition(T1 left, T2 right) -> decltype(left+right)` here. Is it possible?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to overload it with a self-referential return type. If decltype(left+right) is the return type you want, do you need an overload? If so, you share a type with the normal operator+, but something about your implementation is different... what error are you given, if any?

Comment: For clarification, I meant the caller uses `auto added = addition(left, right)`, the original doesn't need to be made auto. The exception is where the return type references the arguments, which is what you appear to be doing in this case. Have you made any progress?